# Iterating backwards in Javascript with a For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I know this is a newbie question, but I need help with iterating backwards. My for loop problem is that I have to iterate backwards by 5 from 100. And I have to console.log all numbers excluding 0. This is what I have.

```
for(var i=100; i >= 0; i-=5)
    console.log(i);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to print out the iteration backwards without 0? Sorry if this is simple, I was having a real hard time with it.

Comment: So what is the question ? What is not working ?

Comment: If it´s excluding 0, it should be i > 0 instead of i >= 0

Comment: Were you truly unable to solve this problem on your own?

Comment: I was getting an error because it keeps printing out 0. So I have to exclude 0 in the console.log. Juvian helped me out there I think.

Comment: One suggestion : open your console and see in the result.

Comment: @TravisJ I wasn't truly. Like I said I"m new to this. :/

Comment: The console is your friend

Comment: Thanks guys. @juvian your solution worked! I've had my head in my hands for an hour. I appreciate it

Comment: Good luck on the rest ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems straight forward:

```js
for(var i=100; i > 0; i-=5) {
    console.log(i);
  }
```

Let me know if I've missed something you need

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it, but you do need to remove the "=" from your expression.  This is a different variation.

```
var i; 

for(i=100; i > 0; i-=5){
    console.log(i);
}
```